# Software (not app) To Read Underlying iPhone Data

Tags: iphone

About a year ago I came across a piece of software that was around $30 that said it could read the underlying data in an iPhone.  I bookmarked it and still I cant find it.  It said it could read and export any of the Notes, SMS Text Messages, Call History, etc.  Essentially, if it was on the iPhone it could get to it.

Does anyone recall seeing such software?  Its not an App.  This is installable software and it ran on the PC and Mac.  I've got both so if anyone knows of anything else then I'm open to investigating that too. Its for the iPhone 3G.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's any software that can do it without jailbreaking the device.

**[iPhone Explorer](http://www.macroplant.com/iphoneexplorer/)** is free software for Mac and PC that allows you to browse many files and folders without jailbreaking. If you do jailbreak it is also supposed to let you get at MS messages, call history, etc.

I've not used with with a jailbroken device, but can attest that it works reasonably well in its normal mode (it seems to not work as well with iOS 4.2, though you can still browse and such).

Comment: I think thats the one...

Answer (score 2):

you can use [iFun-box](http://www.i-funbox.com/) to have an access to iPhone filesystem from your PC.

AFAIK, it doesnt need a jailbreak.

Comment: It appears to be similar to my recommendation: basic file and folder access unless you jailbreak. Looks like another good option, though.

Answer (score 1):

Try PhoneView, it does what you said and doesn't need jailbreak.

Comment: this one looks very nice.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, SeniorShizzle! Can you please add a link to the software you mention in your answer? It is always helpful to add a link to help the OP to find the right software. Thank you.

Comment: http://www.ecamm.com/mac/phoneview/