# Can iBooks be synced from an iPad to a new computer to save my documents?

Tags: itunes, ipad, books, macos

I formated my Mac after a few years of work and forgot to do books backup because iPad was lightly used. As a result all my books stuck on the iPad and if I want to add some new from a computer it wants to erase the existing books.

With iFile, I tried to copy books, but there are only folders, not epub files.

So is there any way to get them back or somehow combine with new iTunes library? In general I don't need those books readable on mac, just to restore and the ability to add new ones to the iPad.

Comment: What happens if you select transfer purchases to see what books the computer will read from your iPad?

Comment: @bmike nothing, those books aren't purchased

Comment: Apple only assists you in transferring back to iTunes things they know you purchased. They presume you will keep a backup copy of things you add manually to the devices or the computer. All is not lost, you'll just need another program on your computer to get the deed done.

Answer (score 1):

I would evaluate a program like [PhoneView](http://www.ecamm.com/mac/phoneview/) to retrieve the contents you like before setting up an iTunes or iCloud backup solution so you don't end up in this spot going forward. There are probably a hundred apps to load files from iOS to a computer, so you can search for one that matches your needs pretty easily. [DiskAid](http://digidna.net/) also seems to be mentioned regularly even though my favorite is PhoneView.

Here are some relevant details to flesh out how this will work:

- [Software (not app) To Read Underlying iPhone Data](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5224/software-not-app-to-read-underlying-iphone-data)
- [How to transfer a file from iPhone to computer when there is no Internet?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/52332/how-to-transfer-a-file-from-iphone-to-computer-when-there-is-no-internet)
- [How can I back up my app data?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/45037/how-can-i-back-up-my-app-data)
- [On iPad's iBooks, is there a way to sync and download all ebooks purchased else where?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/48198/on-ipads-ibooks-is-there-a-way-to-sync-and-download-all-ebooks-purchased-else)

I have also heard many people express happiness at [iExplorer](http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/) for doing the same sort of recovery / transfer of files from an iOS device. Perhaps it will do a better job with your device since you remarked that several of the suggested apps didn't work for you in the comments.

Comment: saves only folders which i already could get via ifile

Comment: These tools work for most - your device might be corrupt if three tools that normally work to retrieve epub documents don't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download [DiskAid](http://digidna.net) (free trial). You can transfer all your music, books and apps over to iTunes from your iPhone.
2. Connect your iPhone to the PC. Open DiskAid.
3. Copy over your books and any other data you wish to backup.
4. Add the recovered `epub` files to iTunes, just like you did previously.
5. Do that for all other media type you wish to restore.
6. Sync your iPad. The content will be restored.

Comment: didn't found any books

Comment: Then there’s something wrong with your device.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running Windows, you can try [Library Tunes](http://www.librarytunes.com) to change the ID of your new iTunes library to that of your old library.  It recovers this ID, so you don't need access to your old computer.  Library Tunes guides you through the process and automates quite a bit.  You can also use it to "enable" a whole bunch of computers you can manually manage your Apple device with.

Answer (score 0):

Those folders are ePubs converted by iBooks.

Copy using your favorite app to a folder on your hard drive *or* use [iExplorer](http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/):

- Get to Media - Books
- Export all to a folder on your drive
- Open iTunes, connect to your device
- Once they are all exported try to drag any entire folder named `xxx-xxxx--xxxx.epub` to the iTunes book section
- If it works do this for all
- Re-sync, it should add to both the iPad and your new library

The issue is that they are linked to another library or messed up with an Apple id.